# Pycharm is not recognizing db.sqlite3 file

Tags: python, mysql, django, database, sqlite

I am learning django and while practicing i came across a db.sqlite3 file that pycharm was not recognizing. I dragged and dropped it in db browser sqllite and i got an error "no database file opened". So what should i do? Can anyone help? If you want a clear idea of what i was doing please refer to last section(i.e project 3) of the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_uQrJ0TkZlc&ab_channel=ProgrammingwithMosh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not drag and drop the db.sqlite3 file. Please follow the below step-

open db browser for sqlite -> Select File(top left corner) ->open database

Select the db.sqlite3 file from your project folder. That should be it.